# Spring + JPA + Hibernate: No inserts at startup

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, persist, postconstruct

I'm executing a method at startup time with `@PostConstruct` annotation. This method has to check a value stored in a table in DB. If it doesn't exist, then it has to insert it. The checking of the value in DB is done correctly, however if I had to persist it, it won't write it to DB. It doesn't throw any exception and `persist()` is executed (apparently) without problems, only the value is not inserted in DB.

Moreover, once everything is up, if I manually call that method (from a Controller, for example), it will insert the value correctly.

```
@PostConstruct
public void insertIfNecessary()
{
   Request r = Request.findRequestForUser(this.me);
   if ( r == null )
   {
      r = new Request();
      r.setOwner(this.me);
      r.persist();
   }
}
```

Do you know what may be wrong?

Best regards,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the transaction is commited, not rolled back.

add @Transactional to the method

---

**Added:**

The second thing should make sure is that the `@Transactional(readonly=false)` annotation is taken in account! If you use Spring Proxy AOP (not AspectJ) then this means, that the method annotated with `@Transactional(readonly=false)` must bean (directly) invoked from an other bean.

Comment: I also tried calling that method from a `@Service` class. It's executed at startup time, but no inserts are performed. However, calling the method from a Controller, works.

Comment: @miguel perher: I have added some more details